# Perl Need to Compare Two Data Structures and Return Differences

Tags: perl, comparison

I have two data structures with a mix of hashes and arrays.  How can I compare the two data structures and return their differences, something like perl's Test::Harness module, but I don't want to actually run a unit test.  ...or is there a way to tun Test::Harness without actually running a unit test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=646926) says that [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDeep), [Data::Compare](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aCompare), and [Data::Match](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aMatch) are your friends. Those packages don't seem to be geared towards producing detailed diffs but you might be able to hack in a callback to keep track of the precise differences.

Comment: neither Test::Deep nor Data::Compare are geared towards producing detailed diffs - did you miss a 'not' from your second sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Test::Deep::NoTest (from [Test::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Deep/)) might be what you are looking for, giving the functions of Test::Deep outside a test script (eq_deeply, cmp_deeply, etc). Look at using deep_diag() to see what the differences are.

[Data::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Compare) - also gives functions returning boolean responses (rather like using `cmp` on the command line for files), but (from memory) is harder to return what those differences are.

I used the former most recently, probably to get the deep_diag() details that Data::Compare didn't provide, but I haven't tried parsing the response.