# Diff a data structure with a separate added and removed sections

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

let's say I have the following

```
my $clean = {
    foo => 1,
    bar => 2,
    baz => 3,
};


my $dirty => {
     foo    => 1,
     bar    => 3,
     blargh => 4,
};


my $differ = Differ->new; #made up object

$differ->compare( $clean, $dirty );


$differ->added;   # blargh
$differ->removed; # baz
$differ->updated; # bar
```

The above is perhaps a very novel example of what I'my trying to do (and my returns may not be complex enough ). Are there any modules that can do this for me?

I'm basically trying to figure out how to compute what to send to a remote server by what's changed. The module should in theory be able to handle a complex data structure including arrays (self referencing not required )

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011632/perl-need-to-compare-two-data-structures-and-return-differences

Comment: You have a typo in your example code. `my $dirty => {` should be `my $dirty = {`.

Answer (score 0):

Data::Diff doesn't quite have the nice OO interface you're looking for, but it seems to do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Diff;

my $clean = {
    foo => 1,
    bar => 2,
    baz => 3,
};

my $dirty = {
     foo    => 1,
     bar    => 3,
     blargh => 4,
};

my $diff = Data::Diff->new($clean, $dirty)->raw();

say "Added: ", join(", ", sort keys %{ $diff->{uniq_b} });
say "Removed: ", join(", ", sort keys %{ $diff->{uniq_a} });
say "Updated: ", join(", ", sort keys %{ $diff->{diff} });
```

Which as per your example outputs:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ ./data_diff.pl 
Added: blargh
Removed: baz
Updated: bar
```